# Create a Factory with MEF

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I basically have a class that has a factory method that takes in a type of Product we have and returns an implementation of IProfileService specifically able to handle that product. If I wanted to use MEF so that I could Implement the different implementations of the IProfileService in another DLL that will only get installed when that particular product gets installed what would be a good approach?

My first thought was an ImportMany with MetaData to describe what product it handles and then just use a LINQ query in my factory method to compare the passed in product to the MetaData. Does this sound good or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that approach is will work just fine. I can't think of another way that would be better.

A technique that could be used with this approach is Lazy loading. See [this great article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF) on MEF. By using `Lazy<T>` in your exports, your IProfileService objects won't be created until you need them.

Comment: Also thank you for that article it is one of the best MEF ones I have read.